# Hide page extension when first time loaded on server.. how can i do this task?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple task but I don't know about this. When we run a page for the first time the extension will be hidden like `Default.aspx` run on the browser for the first time `.aspx` will hidden.

Comment: Google "URL rewriting"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [URL Rewrite IIS module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) to allow the URLs typed and seen by the user to be completely different form the URLs used by the application.